# how to know if a dom element is a certain type of tag

Tags: dom, element

Sorry I am pretty new to programming so bear with me.

An example is if I want to know if a dom node is a p or a h1 tag.

I can't write if(node === 'h1') since the node is not represented as a string but actual tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's think something first. Suppose you have the `node`, now you want to know what tag the node is, right? There is a question, how have you gotten that node? If you have gotten that `node` by a `tag name` then you already know the tag name. But if you have gotten that `node` by `id` or `class` or something else then you can find the `tag name` by simply calling the `tagName` property.

Something like:

```
var node = document.getElementById("node_id");
node.tagName;
```

This will give you the `tag name` you want(e.g.H1, P, H2 etc).

Best of luck

Comment: yes that's it! it's tagname. thank you!! i realized that i was searching "how to find the value of a node element"...it was the way I was googling...which was not very good :/